# How to use context functions in an event listener

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, event-listener, react-context

I'm new to React, even newer to web sockets, I tried, but I can't seem to figure this out. I have an app to order drinks. I open web sockets, so all clients who are signed in under a certain username can update their data every time the data in the database gets updated (if there is a simpler way, tell me, i might try it). So the problem is, i have a context, called General info, where all the data is stored, such as orders, items to be ordered and so on. For better usage the context variable contains also a function, which, with the help of the server, reloads the data, originally set like this:

```js
reload: async (
    ...what: Array<ReloadTypes>
  ) => {console.log("context original function")},
  isLoaded: false,
  places: [""],
  items: [{ name: "", more: [{ value1: "", value2: "" }, ""] }],
  ingredients: [{ value1: "", value2: "" }, ""],
  orders: [
    {
      orderId: "",
      for: "",
      time: "",
      items: [{ name: "", amount: 0, more: [""] }],
    },
  ],
  
  // then later i do this in the functional component
  const context = {
    reload,
    isLoaded,
    places,
    items,
    ingredients,
    orders,
  }
```

Well, as it goes, these values get overwritten later in the context file, into something complicated, and probably useless in this matter. What matters is, that the value changes.
In another file, I have this login functions and all, and right now when you sign in, a useEffect hook gets called, that creates a connection, and an event listener as well.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    function onMessageFunction(message: MessageEvent) {
      const data = JSON.parse(message.data);
      if (data.type === "reload") {
          GeneralInfoContext.reload("orders");
        
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
    console.log(GeneralInfoContext.reload);
    if (isSignedIn) {
      socket.current = new  WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000");
      socket.current.addEventListener("open", () => {
        console.log("opened websocket connection! ");
      });
      socket.current.addEventListener("message", onMessageFunction);
    }
    return () => {
      socket.current = undefined;
    };
  }, [isSignedIn, GeneralInfoContext.reload]);
```

Here lies the problem. The event listener, that is created, uses the default value of the context function reload(), not the overwritten one. So as a result, nothing happens, well, in this example i'd get the console log, but that is not the result is am hoping for.
The question is, how to create an event listener, where i use the correct, updated reloa() function, and not the original context value?
Now there is probably a bunch of wrong stuff in the effect hook, but i can figure that out later, much of it is not finished yet, but this is as far as i got trying to keep the event listener up to date, and much of the stuff is only so in attempt to fix it. I will be grateful for your insight

Comment: Not super familiar with react, sorry - but rando guess - needs bind?  e.g. .addEventListener("open", () => {...your function...}.bind(this))

Comment: Or bind(socket) and then "this" is the socket itself in the function